# ¿Cómo puedo convertir este programa de python en un multiproceso?

Tags: python, fibonacci

Me han solicitado para una pŕactica de la carrera que transforme el siguiente código en multiproceso:

```
import sys
import multiprocessing

def nombre_fibonacci(n):

    if n == 0:

        res = 0

    elif n == 1:

        res = 1

    else:

        res = nombre_fibonacci(n-1) + nombre_fibonacci(n-2)
    
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if len(sys.argv) > 1:

        sys.argv.pop(0)


        mitad = int(len(sys.argv)/2)

        for i in range(len(sys.argv)):

            a = int(sys.argv[i])

            if i < mitad:

                p = multiprocessing.Process(target=nombre_fibonacci(a))

                p.start()
            
            else:

                p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=nombre_fibonacci(a))

                p2.start()
    
    else:

        print("falta numero")
```

El código es una función recursiva de Fibonacci, llevo ya 2 semanas con esto y sigo sin entender cómo aplicar el tema del multi proceso.

Estoy probando este nuevo código, pero al ejecutarlo me aparece el siguiente error:

```
luis@Debian:~/Documentos$ python3 fibonacci-multi.py 5 10 12
1
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/luis/Documentos/fibonacci-multi.py", line 36, in <module>
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=nombre_fibonacci(a))
  File "/home/luis/Documentos/fibonacci-multi.py", line 17, in nombre_fibonacci
    res = nombre_fibonacci(n-1) + nombre_fibonacci(n-2)
  File "/home/luis/Documentos/fibonacci-multi.py", line 17, in nombre_fibonacci
    res = nombre_fibonacci(n-1) + nombre_fibonacci(n-2)
  File "/home/luis/Documentos/fibonacci-multi.py", line 17, in nombre_fibonacci
    res = nombre_fibonacci(n-1) + nombre_fibonacci(n-2)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Ya es la segunda vez que modifico la pregunta con los nuevos códigos y no sé que más hacer.

Comment: Con respecto al ultimo error que publicaste. Si tu función no retorna ningún valor, que esperas que haga `nombre_fibonacci(n-1) + nombre_fibonacci(n-2)`? Tienes que añadir un `return res` al final.

Comment: En la última edición habías cambiado el `return res` por un `print(res)` con lo que la función `nombre_fibonacci` no retornaba nada. Prueba ahora. De todos modos, te añado una respuesta que funciona (más o menos).

Answer (score 2):

Ya tienes una función que calcula Fibonacci para un entero determinado.

Tu programa recibe una lista de enteros y debe calcular Fibonacci para cada uno de ellos. En lugar de hacerlo secuencial, te piden hacerlo en paralelo con `MultiProcessing`

El objeto [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) que ofrece un medio conveniente de paralelizar la ejecución de una función a través de múltiples valores de entrada, distribuyendo los datos de entrada a través de procesos (paralelismo de datos). Si no indicas el número de procesos, esto se ajustara automáticamente según las capacidades de la CPU.

#### Solución

Suponiendo que el usuario a ingresado tres valores enteros en la línea de comandos,

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

args = [5, 10, 15]                        
with Pool() as p:                         
    print(p.map(nombre_fibonacci, args))
```

produce:

```
[5, 55, 610]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

¿Cómo funciona? Con `with Pool() as p:` creas un context manager. Lo importante es `p`, un objeto que tiene un método `map`.

¿Qué hace este `map()`? Toma como primer argumento el nombre de una función y como segundo una lista de argumentos. Con eso `map()` llama n-veces a la función, pasandole un argumento cada vez.

Los resultados son recolectados y devueltos en una lista, la que imprimimos.

Comment: Gracias, estoy probando el código que me indicas, pero me sale un error diciéndome que el nombre "Pool" no está definido. (ya tengo importado el multiprocessing).

Comment: @LuisGarciaJimenez. `from multiprocessing import Pool`

Comment: No me funciona, me aparece un código de error del multiprocessing demasiado largo para ponerlo aquí en los comentarios.

Comment: @LuisGarciaJimenez Al menos edita la pregunta original para añadir el código que has probado. Seguramente, te falte _blindar_ el código del hilo principal para que no lo vuelvan a lanzar los hilos hijos (con un bloque `if __name__ == "__main__"`)

Comment: Perdón, soy nuevo en stackoverflow y no sé muy bien cómo funciona jajaja, ahora lo hago

Answer (score 0):

La *paralelización* podemos hacerla con los argumentos de entrada al script:

```py
import sys
from multiprocessing import Pool

def fibonacci(n: int) -> int:

    if n == 0:
        res = 0
    elif n == 1:
        res = 1
    else:
        res = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
    
    return res

def main(args: list[int]) -> int:

  with Pool() as p:                         
    res = p.map(fibonacci, args)
  
  return sum(res)

if __name__ == "__main__":

  if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
    print("falta numero")
  else:
    args = [int(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]]
    res = main(args)
    print(f"Resultado: {res}")
```

La función `main` es la encargada de crear el pool de procesos en los que irá lanzando el cálculo fibonacci por cada entero. Su llamada está protegida por un `if __name__ == "__main__"` para que sólo sea llamada por el proceso principal.

Se puede probar así:

```sh
$ python fibonacci_multi.py 34 5 2
Resultado: 5702893
```

Este cálculo tarda bastante. Las llamadas recursivas se repiten muchas veces calculando muchas veces los mismos elementos de la sucesión.

Podemos hacer una optimización usando un caché:

```py
from functools import cache

@cache
def fibonacci(n: int) -> int:

    if n == 0:
        res = 0
    elif n == 1:
        res = 1
    else:
        res = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
    
    return res
```

Aún con todo, los cachés no se comparten entre procesos, por lo que se repetirán los mismos cálculos en los distintos procesos.

Por otra parte, la recursividad en python está limitada, lo que puede comprobarse si se intentan calcular números grandes:

```sh
$ python fibonacci_multi.py 1000
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Como este problema de recursividad es propio de la función tal como estaba definida, se podría parar aquí; pero voy a intentar mejorarla. Voy a crear mi propia versión de caché que recorra la secuencia de números fibonacci desde el primero para ir llenando la cache en secuencia, lo que evita llamadas recursivas:

```py
cache = [0,1]

def fibonacci(n: int) -> int:

    for i in range(len(cache), n+1):
        cache.append(cache[i-1] + cache[i-2])
   
    return cache[n]
```

Como código final:

```py
import sys
from multiprocessing import Pool

cache = [0,1]

def fibonacci(n: int) -> int:

    for i in range(len(cache), n+1):
        cache.append(cache[i-1] + cache[i-2])
   
    return cache[n]

def main(args: list[int]) -> int:

  with Pool() as p:                         
    res = p.map(fibonacci, args)
  
  return sum(res)

if __name__ == "__main__":

  if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
    print("falta numero")
  else:
    args = [int(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]]
    res = main(args)
    print(f"Resultado: {res}")
```